# Spring AOP doesn't see the method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

In my project I have **AspectService** class, that I use to log all controller methods:

```
@Component
@SLFJ
@Aspect
public class AspectService {
   @Pointcut("@annotation(com.aleksandr0412.bookstore.annotations.Audit) && execution(public * *(..))")
public void publicAspectAudit() {
}

@Around(value = "publicAspectAudit()")
public Object aspect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    AuditMessage auditMessage = new AuditMessage();
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    auditMessage.setUuid(uuid);
    auditMessage.setAuditCode(((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(Audit.class).value());
    auditMessage.setEventCode(EventCode.START);
    auditMessage.setTimeStart(LocalDateTime.now());
    auditMessage.setUsername("");
    Object[] args = Arrays.stream(joinPoint.getArgs())
            .filter(arg -> !(arg instanceof UriComponentsBuilder)).toArray();
    auditMessage.setParams(om.writeValueAsString(args));

    log.info(auditMessage.toString());

//-----
```

My project has 3 modules: first - audit and **AspectService**, second and third is executable modules with different controllers.
My problem is that in one module public controller-methods with **@Audit** annotations work true, but in another module, **AspectService** doesn't see them.

Work true:

```
 @Audit(AuditCode.AUTHOR_CREATE)
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<AuthorDto> createAuthor(AuthorDto authorDto, UriComponentsBuilder componentsBuilder) {
        log.info("createAuthor with {} - start ", authorDto);
        AuthorDto result = service.addAuthor(authorDto);
        URI uri = componentsBuilder.path("/api/author/" + result.getId()).buildAndExpand(result).toUri();
        log.info("createAuthor end with {}, with result {}", authorDto, result);

        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(result);
    }
```

Doesn't work:

```
  @Audit(AuditCode.CREATE_USER)
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> createUser(
            UserDTO userDTO,
            UriComponentsBuilder componentsBuilder
    ) {
        log.info("createUser with {} - start ", userDTO);
        if (userDTO == null) {
            throw new EmptyException();
        }
        UserDTO result = userService.add(userDTO);
        URI uri = componentsBuilder.path("/api/user/" + result.getId()).buildAndExpand(result).toUri();
        log.info("createUser end with result {}", result);
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(result);
    }
```

When I try to debug it, in second example I don't visit **AspectService** class.
Where am I make mistake?

Comment: So you have three separate Spring Boot Apps?

Comment: Yes, 2 separate executable, and 1 - audit, uses like library

Comment: And in the 2 execs you have ComponentScan enabled for the package where the AspectService is in?

Comment: Ty, it was problem with ComponentScan

Comment: Great. Please add this as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add @ComponentScan with AspectService package to second module. It solved my problem